# Correct test for values in if statement in Bash

Tags: bash

What is the correct test for an if statement in bash. I am not certain if the second statement assigns a value or if it tests equivalency.

```
if [[ "$user_has_mfa" == "NO" ]]; then
   .... do stuff...
fi
```

Or

```
if [[ "$user_has_mfa" = "NO" ]]; then
  .. do stuff..
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=` is the standard operator for string equality in conditional expressions. There is no assignment operator in `[[ ... ]]` commands, so there is no ambiguity between `=` and `bash`'s `==` operator; they are equivalent.

For `[`, `=` is the *only* portable operator. `==` is allowed by `bash`, but not, for instance, by `dash`. If you are concerned with portability, only `[ "$user_has_mfa" = "NO" ]` would be acceptable.

In an arithmetic context, there *is* a difference between `=` and `==`, because assignment is allowed. `=` for is assignment, and `==` for is equality testing. For example:

```
$ x=0  # shell assignment
$ ((x = 3))  # arithmetic assignment
$ if (( x == 3 )); then echo "x is 3"; fi
x is 3
```

You are also subject to the same type of "wrote `=` when I mean `==`" errors that C programmers need to worry about.

```
$ x=3
$ if ((x=4)); then echo "x equals 4"; fi
x equals 4
$ echo $x
4
```

Answer (score 4):

They're equivalent. From the [Bash manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> ```
> string1 == string2
> string1 = string2
> ```
>
> True  if  the strings are equal.  `=` should be used with the `test` command for POSIX conformance.  When used with the `[[` command, this performs pattern matching as described above (Compound Commands).

Answer (score 1):

One equal should be fine.

```
if [[ "$user_has_mfa" = "NO" ]]; then
  .. do stuff..
fi
```

You can use

```
-eq     for integers
=, ==   for strings
```